# Query with TSQL ( MS SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Good morning,I have this table in MS SQL server:

```
id_cliente  numero_telefono
1           2232323232
1           342424
2           7878787
3           5464564
3           999999
3           22222
```

I want extract the data in this way:

```
id_cliente   num_telefono1   num_telefono2   num_telefono3
1            2232323232      342424
2            7878787
3            5464564         999999          22222
```

is possible with `PIVOT` command of TSQL ? I have tryed, but I'm not able to do this..

I've tried the following query:

```
select id_cliente,[t1],[t2],[t3] 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id_cliente,numero_telefono 
    FROM my_tabella 
) as A 
PIVOT ( MAX(numero_telefono) FOR numero_telefono in ([t1],[t2],[t3] ) ) as B
```

Comment: What did you try and what did you get? Please post the code. Note that PIVOT or any other workaround will work only if the maximum number of phone numbers is known in advance

Comment: select id_cliente,[t1],[t2],[t3]

FROM (
        SELECT id_cliente,numero_telefono
        FROM my_tabella ) as A
        
pivot 
(  MAX(numero_telefono)
 FOR numero_telefono in ([t1],[t2],[t3] ) ) as B  ( NB: the colums are both INT )

Comment: PIVOT requires that you know the names of the `PIVOT` members in advance (eg [1],[2],[3]). You can get the order of each phone number for each customer using the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowing function.

Answer (score 4):

If you have up to three telephone numbers, I would do this with "explicit" pivot logic:

```
select id_cliente,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then numero_telefono end) as telefono1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then numero_telefono end) as telefono2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then numero_telefono end) as telefono3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_cliente order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by id_cliente;
```

If you can have any number of telephone numbers, then the number of columns varies and you need a dynamic pivot.

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT requires that you know the names of the PIVOT members in advance (eg [1],[2],[3]).

You can get the order of each phone number for each customer using the ROW_NUMBER() windowing function and then pivot by the row number

eg

```
select 
    id_cliente,
    [1] AS num_telefono1,
    [2] AS num_telefono2,
    [3] AS num_telefono3
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id_cliente,numero_telefono ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_cliente ORDER BY id_cliente) AS seq
    FROM my_tabella 
) as A 
PIVOT ( MAX(numero_telefono) FOR seq in ([1],[2],[3] ) ) as B
```

This will return the following data:

```
id_cliente  num_telefono1 num_telefono2 num_telefono3
1           2232323232   342424     NULL
2           7878787      NULL       NULL
3           5464564      999999     22222
```

Comment: Thanks ... but I did not understand why my query returns all NULL values​​:  select id_cliente,[t1],[t2],[t3] 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id_cliente,numero_telefono 
    FROM my_tabella3 
) as A 
PIVOT ( MAX(numero_telefono) FOR numero_telefono in ([t1],[t2],[t3] ) ) as B

Comment: You get `NULL` because there is no value to display for this column. If a client has only one number, there's nothing to display for columns 2 or 3. If you want to return a different value in this case, eg an empty string, you'll have to use `COALESCE([2],'')`. This will only work if the numbers are stored as text. If you store them as decimals, you'll have to convert them to text before using `COALESCE`, eg `COALESCE(CAST([2] AS VARCHAR(15)),'')`

Answer (score 0):

Let we have a table W

```
SELECT * FROM W
```

[image]

The code only helps the above scenario.

```
WITH CTE (ID,MARK,[ROW])
AS
(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) [ROW]
FROM    W)

SELECT A.ID,A.MARK,B.MARK,C.MARK
FROM (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROW = 1) A
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROW = 2) B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE ROW = 3) C ON A.ID = C.ID
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This code will adjust automatically with the number of records in the same group. In your question, we had maximum of 3 records in the group. Here we have 7 in the below example.

```
--INITIAL SETTINGS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE NAME = 'W')
    DROP TABLE W

CREATE  TABLE W
(ID INT, MARK INT)
INSERT INTO W VALUES(1,12),(1,24)
                    ,(2,23),(2,20),(2,25)
                    ,(3,10),(3,11),(3,10),(3,11),(3,17),(3,19)
GO

--DECLARATIONS
DECLARE @a INT = 1
DECLARE @b INT = 
(
SELECT  MAX([ROW]) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) [ROW] FROM W) LU
)
DECLARE @P1 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A.ID,A.MARK'
DECLARE @P2 VARCHAR(MAX) = 'FROM    (SELECT * FROM @tab WHERE ROW = 1) A'
DECLARE @FINAL VARCHAR(MAX)

IF @a < @b
BEGIN
    --SELECT @a,@b
    DECLARE @tab TABLE (ID INT, MARK INT,[ROW] INT)
    INSERT INTO @tab
    SELECT  ID,MARK,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) FROM W
    --SELECT * FROM @tab

    WHILE @a < @b
    BEGIN
        SET @P1 = @P1 + ','+ CHAR(@a+65) +'.MARK'
        SET @P2 = @P2 + ' LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM @tab WHERE ROW = '+ CAST(@a + 1 AS VARCHAR(3))+') ' + CHAR(@a+65) +' ON A.id = '+ CHAR(@a+65) +'.id '
        SET @a = @a + 1
    END
END

SET @FINAL = 'SELECT '+ @P1 + ' ' + @P2

EXEC    
(   'DECLARE @tab TABLE (ID INT, MARK INT,[ROW] INT)

    INSERT INTO @tab
    SELECT  ID,MARK,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID DESC) FROM W

    '+ @FINAL
)
```

As per the above code, the source table will be

[image]

And the obtained result will be

[image]

Comment: Why a down vote?, What made it useless..pls comment.